# how to get next element that is visible in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have a some elements and previous and next links in each of those elements. 
As if i click on next i want to add a class only to the next div which is visible and i want to skip the divs which are hidden and if div is hidden add class to next div which is visible after hidden element. for that i written something like this

```
$('.next').click(function(){
   $('.slide').removeClass('highZindex');
   $(this).closest('.slide').next('.slide:visible').addClass('highZindex')
})
```

i just want to remove added class from all of those element and just have to add to the next visible element but whats happening is if click on next link and if the next div is hidden it skips all elements and directly goes to last div and class is also not adding to any element.

```js
$('.slide').first().addClass('highZindex');


$('.prev').click(function(){
$('.slide').removeClass('highZindex');
$(this).closest('.slide').prev('.slide:visible').addClass('highZindex')
})

$('.next').click(function(){
   $('.slide').removeClass('highZindex');
   $(this).closest('.slide').next('.slide:visible').addClass('highZindex')
})
```

```css
.slide {border:1px solid; height:200px; width:200px;position:absolute;top:0px; left:0px; background-color:#fff; }
.highZindex {z-index:1000}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide">1  <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a> <a href="#" class="next">next</a></div>
<div class="slide">2 <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a> <a href="#" class="next">next</a></div>
<div class="slide">3 <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a> <a href="#" class="next">next</a></div>
<div class="slide" style="display:none;">4 <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a> <a href="#" class="next">.next</a></div>
<div class="slide">5 <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a> <a href="#" class="next">next</a></div>
<div class="slide">6 <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a> <a href="#" class="next">next</a></div>
<div class="slide">7 <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a> <a href="#" class="next">next</a></div>
```

Comment: Do you really want make that using z-index?

Comment: yes, as it is simple

Comment: is there another to achieve same result?? @André Pacheco

Comment: Why not add a class "visible" ( with css display:block) and "hidden" (with css display: none )?
Using that you don't need to put position absolute neither use z-index.

Comment: Another issue that you will face using .next() or prev() is that when you reach the last element or the first in the div you won't be able to go further. The workaround is to disable the "buttons" (if i may call them that) as soon as it reach the last or the first element.

Comment: you are correct but in there is a use case that some elements are hidden(with css display:none) from the beginning i dont want to show them.  that is the reason why i'm using this approach and in my project these are dynamic elements some elements are hidden from beginning and have to show and hide them if user selects something in current div. so i dont want to messup is display:block or none as im using these controls for another purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Just change from '**prev**' / '**next**' to '**prevAll**' / '**nextAll**' and **select first item** from list.

*Changed lines*

```
$(this).closest('.slide').prevAll('.slide:visible').first().addClass('highZindex');
$(this).closest('.slide').nextAll('.slide:visible').first().addClass('highZindex');
```

If you don't want looping prev btn you can add condition:

```
$('.prev').click(function(){
    if(!($(this).closest('.slide').prevAll('.slide:visible').length == 0)) {
        $('.slide').removeClass('highZindex');
        $(this).closest('.slide').prevAll('.slide:visible').first().addClass('highZindex'); 
    }
})
```